# How to stop the roots of a cubic from becoming mixed up when plotting the 3 roots as contour plots?

Tags: python, sorting, contour, polynomials, cubic

I have a function which determines the roots of a complex cubic. I am solving the cubic for a variety of k0 and k1 values and showing the solutions as contour plots. Since the cubic has three roots, I produce 3 contour plots for the real parts and 3 for the imaginary parts. However, sometimes you can clearly see that sections of the contour plots for one root really should be swapped with a different contour plot - all the contours should be continuous. I have tried various "sorting methods" which you can see, but none of them fully fix it. What can I do so that the roots don't get mixed up resulting in non-continuous contours.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
Ra = 2e4
Pr = 0.1
Omega = 1e5
zeta = 1e-4
deltaN = 0.05
L = 55

def polynomial(k):
    m = 1
    delta_k = m**2 * np.pi**2 + k[0]**2
    a_3 = delta_k
    a_2 = 1j*(Ra * Pr * delta_k * k[0])/Omega + (Pr + zeta + 1)*delta_k**2
    a_1 = 1j*(Ra * Pr * delta_k**2 * k[0] * (Pr + zeta)/Omega) + k[1] * Pr * zeta * (delta_k**2/L**2 + delta_k) - deltaN * Ra * Pr * k[0]**2 + (Pr * zeta + Pr + zeta) * delta_k**3
    a_0 = 1j*(Pr * zeta * k[0] * (Ra * Pr * delta_k**3/Omega + k[1] * Omega * deltaN * delta_k / L**2)) + Pr * zeta * (k[1] * (Pr * delta_k**3 / L**2 + delta_k**2) - deltaN * Ra * delta_k * k[0]**2 + delta_k**4)
    x_K = np.roots([a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0])
    # x_K = np.sort_complex(x_K)
    x_K = sorted(x_K, key=lambda x: x.imag)
    # x_K = sorted(x_K, key=lambda x: x.real)
    # if x_K[2].imag >= 0: 
    #     x_K[-1], x_K[-2] = x_K[-2], x_K[-1]
    # if x_K[0].imag >= x_K[2].imag:
    #     x_K[0], x_K[-1] = x_K[-1], x_K[0]
    if x_K[0].real >= x_K[1].real:
        x_K[0], x_K[1] = x_K[1], x_K[0]
    # if x_K[1].real >= x_K[2].real:
    #     x_K[1], x_K[2] = x_K[2], x_K[1]
    return x_K


# Create arrays of k[0] and k[1] values for contour plot
k0, k1 = np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(0, 5e2, 100)
K0, K1 = np.meshgrid(k0, k1)

# Get roots for each pair of k[0], k[1] value
roots = np.array([polynomial([K0[i, j], K1[i, j]]) for i in range(100) for j in range(100)], dtype=complex)

ky_max = []
Qz_max = []

# Plot real and imaginary parts of roots separately in one figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(13.6, 7.6), constrained_layout=True)
axs = axs.ravel()
for i in range(3):
    cnt = axs[i].contourf(K0, K1, roots[:, i].real.reshape(K0.shape), levels=20, cmap='coolwarm')
    axs[i].set_title(f'Real part of root {i+1}')
    axs[i].set_xlabel('$k_y$')
    axs[i].set_ylabel('$Q_z$')
    # axs[i].set_yscale('log')
    fig.colorbar(cnt, ax=axs[i])

    cnt = axs[i+3].contourf(K0, K1, roots[:, i].imag.reshape(K0.shape), levels=20, cmap='coolwarm')
    axs[i+3].set_title(f'Imaginary part of root {i+1}')
    axs[i+3].set_xlabel('$k_y$')
    axs[i+3].set_ylabel('$Q_z$')
    # axs[i+3].set_yscale('log')
    cbar1 = fig.colorbar(cnt, ax=axs[i+3])
    cbar1.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
    
    max_val = np.max(roots[:, i].real)
    print(f'Maximum value for real part of root {i+1} is: {max_val}')
    
    max_val = np.max(roots[:, i].real)
    max_index = np.argmax(roots[:, i].real)
    k0_max, k1_max = K0.flatten()[max_index], K1.flatten()[max_index]
    
    axs[i].scatter(k0_max, k1_max, s=150, color='yellow', marker='x', label=f'Max value {max_val:.4f}')
    axs[i].legend(loc=0)
    
    ky_max.append(K0.flatten()[max_index])
    Qz_max.append(K1.flatten()[max_index])

    
    print(f'k_y for root {i+1} is: {k0_max}')
    print(f'Q_z for  root {i+1} is: {k1_max}')

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    axs[2].spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)
    axs[2].spines[axis].set_color("green")
    axs[5].spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)
    axs[5].spines[axis].set_color("green")


# Create a caption
caption = f'Contour plot showing the real and imaginary components of the roots of the cubic for a range of $k_y$ and $Q_z$ values. Where the other variables are given by: Ra$^* = $ {Ra:.1e}, $\Delta N =$ {deltaN}, Pr = {Pr:.1e}, $\zeta =$ {zeta:.1e}, $\Omega =$ {Omega:.1e}, $L$ = {L}.'

# Create a file name
figure_name = f'decay_contour_Ra={Ra:.1e}_Pr={Pr:.1e}_dN={deltaN}'
pdf_file = f'{figure_name}.pdf'
tex_file = f'{figure_name}.tex'

# save the plot as a PDF
plt.savefig(pdf_file)

# create a text file containing the LaTeX code to include the figure
with open(tex_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("\\begin{figure}[h]\n")
    f.write("\\centering\n")
    f.write("\\includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{"+ pdf_file+"}\n")
    f.write("\\caption{"+ caption +"}\n")
    f.write("\\end{figure}\n")


fig2, axs2 = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(11, 8), constrained_layout=True)


for idx_1 in range(3):
    k1_slice = 0
    indices = np.where(K1.flatten() == k1_slice)
    
    root_slice = roots[indices][:,idx_1].real
    
    k1_slice = K0.flatten()[indices]
    root_slice = roots[indices][:,idx_1].real
    
    axs2[0][idx_1].plot(k1_slice, root_slice, color = 'red')
    
    k1_slice_imag = K0.flatten()[indices]
    root_slice_imag = roots[indices][:,idx_1].imag
    
    axs2[1][idx_1].plot(k1_slice, root_slice_imag, color = 'red')
    axs2[1][idx_1].set_xlabel('$k_y$')
        
        
axs2[0][0].set_ylabel('Re$(s)$')
axs2[1][0].set_ylabel('Im$(s)$')

for idx_1 in range(3):
    axs2[0][idx_1].plot(k0, -zeta*(np.pi**2 + k0**2), 'x', markevery=10, color = 'black')

# Create a caption
caption = f'Profiles at the $k_y$ at $Q_z = 0$ showing the real and imaginary components of the roots of the cubic for a range of $k_y$ and $Q_z$ values. Where the other variables are given by: Ra$^* = $ {Ra:.1e}, $\Delta N =$ {deltaN}, Pr = {Pr:.1e}, $\zeta =$ {zeta:.1e}, $\Omega =$ {Omega:.1e}, $L$ = {L}.'

# Create a file name
figure_name = f'decay_profiles_Ra={Ra:.1e}_Pr={Pr:.1e}_dN={deltaN}'
pdf_file = f'{figure_name}.pdf'
tex_file = f'{figure_name}.tex'

# create a text file containing the LaTeX code to include the figure
with open(tex_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("\\begin{figure}[h]\n")
    f.write("\\centering\n")
    f.write("\\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{"+ pdf_file+"}\n")
    f.write("\\caption{"+ caption +"}\n")
    f.write("\\end{figure}\n")
    
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    axs2[0][2].spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)
    axs2[0][2].spines[axis].set_color("green")
    axs2[1][2].spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)
    axs2[1][2].spines[axis].set_color("green")

# save the plot as a PDF
plt.savefig(pdf_file)

plt.show()
```

I've tried np.sort, np.sorted, flapping the roots using if statements etc, nothing works 100%

Comment: Although I understand the problem, it would help if you wrote the equations in non-python form. Otherwise it's incredibly hard to make sense of the python code, since it's solving an unknown equation and the equation is hard to read when it's hidden in the code. I'm guessing the equation is `a_3 z**3 + a_2 z**2 + a_1 z + a_0 == 0`.

Comment: Also I personally find these contour plots hard to read, and would find it much easier to look at a simple plot in the 2d plane, with the x-axis for the real part and the y-axis for the imaginary part of the roots. Then each equation gives three points for the three roots; and the question becomes "How to cluster all the points into three continuous lines"

Comment: @Stef yes that is the correct form of the cubic. Also the purpose of the contours its to show how the solutions to the cubic vary as you vary k0 and k1 (k_y and Q_z).

Answer (score 0):

For two successive polynomials P and Q, I suggest simply solving the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) to pair each root of P to the closest root of Q.

You can use scipy's `linear_sum_assignment` along with `distance_matrix` to find the best assignment of P's roots with Q's roots.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_root_sequence(sequence_of_polynomials):
    r0 = np.roots(sequence_of_polynomials[0])
    roots = [r0]
    for P in sequence_of_polynomials[1:]:
        r1 = np.roots(P)
        _, idx = linear_sum_assignment(distance_matrix(r0.reshape(3, 1), r1.reshape(3,1)))
        r1 = r1[idx]
        roots.append(r1)
        r0 = r1
    return np.array(roots)

sequence_of_polynomials = np.linspace((1,0,0,-1), (1,-7-2j,15+9j,-10-10j), 100)
roots = get_root_sequence(sequence_of_polynomials)

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')

for i in range(3):
    r = roots[:, i]
    ordinal = ('first', 'second', 'third')[i]
    plt.plot(r.real, r.imag, label=f'{ordinal} root')

for triangle, label in zip((roots[0], roots[-1]), ('x³-1', '(x-2)(x-2-i)(x-3-i)')):
    triangle = triangle[[0,1,2,0]]
    plt.plot(triangle.real, triangle.imag, label=label)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Real part')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary part')
plt.show()
```

[image: Roots]